# How to write a function which compares two vectors to see if they have the exact same values by making use of another function?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, binary-search

```
function [tf] = findelt1(w,x)
tf=0;
for i=1:length(w)
    if any(w(i)==x)
        tf=1;
        return;
    end
end
end
```

using findelt1 how can I write a function method1(v,w), v and w being two input vectors, which returns true if all values in v and w are the same and returning false otherwise.
Pseudo code:
default output is true
  for each element a in v
     % use findelt1 that you wrote above
     if a is not in w, return false
So far for method1 I have:

```
function [tf] = method1(v,w)
tf=1;
for i=1:length(v)
    for j=1:length(w)
    if findelt1(w,j)==1
        if v(i)==w(j)
            tf=1;
        else
            tf=0;
        end
    end
    return;
    end
end
end
```

Comment: So what *exactly* is wrong with your current implementation? Does it give you a syntax error? Does it tell you that a subscript is out of range? Does it run but give you an incorrect answer? What inputs are you using to test your function? What outputs do you get? What outputs did you expect? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

**Original Answer:** 
This will make sure they are the same length and that all elements agree. It also checks that the order is the same.  Ex. `v=[1 2 3]` & `w=[3 2 1]` will return false

```
tf = numel(v) == numel(w) && all(v == w);
```

**Updated Answer:**
Just use [isequal](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html) it checks size and contents.  @CitizenInsane beat me to it in the comments.

```
tf = isequal(v,w)
```

Comment: I did consider using numel but was told that their was a way to write this without making use of that. So (sorry for not mentioning) at the moment I'm looking for an answer or explanation without the use of numel

Comment: Do you care about the order?  Should [1,2,3] & [3,2,1] return True or False .  See my edit

Comment: Order does matter (again sorry for not mentioning it). So your example should still return false

Comment: without care for order this should be `(numel(v) == numel(w)) && all(ismember(v, w))`

Comment: @CitizenInsane   Yes that seems to work, but I'm trying to find a solution that doesn't use numel (since I was told their is a way to do this without the use of numel).

Comment: If order matters, you can use directly matlab genuine routine [isequal](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html)

Comment: @CitizenInsane I was editing my answer to mention `isequal` when you commented.  You're to quick

Comment: @AeroEngy More than the avoided use of numel I have to make use of my previous function findelt1 in the method1 function. So even though you make use of isequal how can I use my findelt1 function in the method1 function to accomplish the task stated in the pseudo code?

Comment: Well this now seems like a weird homework problem with arbitrary restrictions.  Being forced to use  `finddelt1` is pointless since it only returns true if a single element if found anywhere within the second array.

Comment: @AeroEngy I 100% agree. The only reason I even asked was because I really didn't know how to find a solution for this the more tedious way. Unfortunately, this is an online course and it does have restrictions (ones that I am not appreciative of). So if you can help me with doing this the more unnecessary way that would be of much assistance. If you choose not to, it is also fine since you did give me a better (yet not allowed) solution already.

Comment: can you just simplify the answer to: 'use isequal'? That'd be great

Comment: I cleaned it up some but left the original answer as well.  @TheBOI  I probably won't go through the trouble of trying to incorporate `finddelt1` it seems overly complicated to try to do it that way and less robust.